# Spyder 3 "Set Console Working Directory" not working

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I've been using Spyder 2 as my default Python IDE for a couple of years already, and while preparing a class on Signal Processing I've stumbled upon the new Spyder 3 on Anaconda and decided to see what it looks like.

First, I've updated the Anaconda distribution on my Ubuntu 16.04 office computer to the newest version (i.e. I had a previous version already installed), and then got quite surprised when the button for "Set Console Working Directory" on the File Explorer (top right, between the "folder" icon and the "up arrow" icon) was missing. I can still change the working directory manually on the IPython console, but it's impractical and certainly won't motivate the students!

Thinking it could be a bug with the conda update, I've then decided to give it a go at downloading and installing the Anaconda for Windows on my home laptop (which is probably what most of the students will do), and it also does not have the "Set Console Working Directory" button.

By then I was thinking the new Spyder version might have abandoned it, but strangely enough, the [Spyder GitHub page](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder) has a screenshot of the new Spyder 3 that HAS this exact same button (again: top right, between the "folder" icon and the "up arrow" icon)!

EDIT: here's a screenshot of how my Spyder looks like in Windows (the big red arrow is pointing towards where the icon should be):

[image]

Does anyone knows if there is a setting option that hides the "Set console working directory" button, or if this is a bug in the more recent Anaconda version that doesn't show it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answering my own question: I've contacted the Spyder developers, and this is "half a bug" :P (my choice of words).

Let me explain:

- The intended functionality for Spyder 3 is to automatically change the console working directory when navigating through the file explorer, therefore the lack of the old button is intentional and is not a bug;
- However, this new functionality is not working at the moment, which is a bug :P

The good news is that this will be fixed for Spyder 3.0.2, which should be out in a few days :)

(I've also been told that Anaconda usually takes a few days to add new versions in their repositories, so it might take a short while until we're able to update Spyder through `conda`)

Comment: I am having Spyder 3.1.4 on Mac and I still see this problem.

Comment: @Sujoy you mean the lack of "Set Console Working Directory" button? If so, as I wrote in my answer above, it has been intentionally removed from the current versions of Spyder.

From what I can tell, the way it currently works is: navigating to a new directory through the address bar at the top right DOES change the current console working directory to wherever you set there; however, navigating through the File Explorer tab DOES NOT change the working directory to what you set, even though the address bar mirrors the changes you set in the File Explorer and vice versa. I hope this helps!

Comment: My point was, it didn't work when I navigated to the current directory. After that when I ran my code it gave FNF Exception. I really don't get it.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your problem correctly; did you navigate to the current directory using the address bar or using the file browser? Did you check the "real" current working directory in the console using `%pwd`? In any case, it seems it is not related to my original question regarding the "Set Console Working Directory" button (or lack thereof), so perhaps you should ask a new question on SO or make a post on the Spyder developers' Google Groups page.

Answer (score 4):

In the case where you're not having your directory change automatically, an alternative option is to manually locate the directory you want to go to and inside of the IPython Console just change to that directory directly.

%cd 'Directory Location'

Just remember to do a sanity check and also run %pwd afterward.

Answer (score 4):

I have been using Spyder 3.0 and faced the same issue. I was able to work-around it like this - go to the directory you want to make as working folder in the right side top option. Close and open up Spyder. It takes this as the working directory.